# What is the difference between data design and data model(ERD)

Tags: database-design

I have already google this question and find the answer in all day.
As I know, data design is many to many table which have list the column,and mark pk and fk.
But why the er-diagram which I have find is also look like this?

Comment: Data design is the process of designing a database.  A data model is one of the outputs of the data design process.

Comment: @Gilbert, your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Data design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) is the process of designing a database.  The main output of a data design is a detailed logical data model of a database.

Some people say that data design also includes all of the needed logical and physical design choices and physical storage parameters needed to generate a design in a Data Definition Language.  Technically, this is database analysis, which is what database analysts (DBAs) are trained to do.

While a person can do both data design and database analysis, these are two different tasks.  data design models the data.  Database analysis takes that model and applies it to one or more database engines (relational, hierarchical, NoSQL).

A logical data model is one of the main outputs of data design.  The data model is usually represented as an entity relationship diagram, or ER diagram.